# Get value of pre-defined input with Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, post

I have a small form which I want to post with Angular and mongodb. 
My problem is that when I post the form, I have a input with a pre-defined value in it ( a username of the current user). This input I have set on display: none.

Now I want to post the form using ng-model, but somehow when I post the form, it does not post the input I just mentioned.

This is the form:

```
<div class="wrapper-small">
  <div class="title dark small">Typ een bericht</div>
  <div class="forum_form">
    <form method="post" ng-submit="onSubmit(messagebox)" name="messagebox">
      <input type="text" style="display:none;" value="testname" name="username" ng-model="forumModel.username"/>
      <textarea id="limitChar" name="message" required="required" ng-model="forumModel.message"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="form_date_button submit-btn">Verzenden</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Angular post method:

```
App.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){

  $scope.forumModel = {};
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
    $http.post('/features', $scope.forumModel)
      .then(function successCallback(response){
      }, function errorCallback(response){
      });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<input type="hidden" value="testname" name="username" ng-model="forumModel.username" />
```

Comment: It seems your code is working, maybe you have any other issues? http://jsfiddle.net/rqckgL7h/6/